# Why is mp4 video broke in webkit on ios 6

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, ios6

I am developing an IOS app using Flex Mobile. to launch Native ios video player I create an instance of StageWebView and load a URL that is pointing to an MP4 file.

This works great as of ios 5.1.x but I just upgraded a device to IOS 6 and this does not work. the video player launches embedded in the webstageview but shows the X through the play button indicating that it can't play the video.

Answer (score 0):

A preset with lower field dominance should do it. Progressive videos play fine